# See group of online user without having to subscribe on openfire chat server

Tags: c#, xmpp, chat, openfire, agsxmpp

Not sure if this question is programming related, but i think SO users might having experience about my problem to share.

is it possible to automatically see online user on specific group without having to subscribe (add as friend/buddy)? so whenever user enter to specific group he/she will automatically see all the online user on the appropriate group. every users are free to enter to any group on the website.

is this can be done on the chat server side by using plugin etc, or can be done on agsxmpp side.

we tried using Conference Room (MUC), but it having limitation only maximum 100 users, on our website number of user entering group can be more than 500 users.

any idea?

**openfire** / **asp.net mvc** / **agsxmpp**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it is impossible to do that.

here is quote from [Alex (agsxmpp forum)](http://forum.ag-software.net/thread/1515-Showing-user-presence-without-having-to-subscribe)

> XMPP requires always mutual subscription. This means the contact you are adding and subscribe to must approve your subscription. Without the approval you get no presence. This means that the contacts you add must either manual or automatically accept this requests. If they will do so everything will work and the server will start sending you presence.